# Laravel 4 routes: modify parameter values in route

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am working with a Laravel CMS called WardrobeCMS (http://wardrobecms.com) and am trying to modify routes to work with my existing cms routes, so I can port over.

WardrobeCMS uses:

```
/post/{slug}
```

and I would like to keep my existing:

```
/{year}/{month}/{slug}
```

If I can combine my 3-part slug into a single {slug}, I can avoid overriding a lot of core functionality, so this is really the best direction I think

I am trying:

```
Route::get('{year}/{month}/{slug}', array(
     'uses' => $wardrobeControllers.'PostController@show',
     'as' => 'wardrobe.posts.show',
     function($year, $month, $slug)
     {
        return $slug = implode('/', array($year, $month, $slug));
     }
   )    
);
```

but it is having no affect; I've looked around for a similar operation but found nothing. Not sure if it is just a syntax error or I'm completely off-track in what I'm trying to do

Wondering if perhaps a before filter isn't the answer, but haven't made anything work yet.

Thanks!

Comment: What is not working, it'll return you only `string`, isn't it ? What you are trying to do in this function ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this, just create another request with your prepared `params` like

```
Route::get('{year}/{month}/{slug}', array(
    'uses' => $wardrobeControllers.'PostController@show',
    'as' => 'wardrobe.posts.show',
    function($year, $month, $slug) {
       // build the params
       $args =  = implode('/', array($year, $month, $slug));

       // create a new request and dispatch it
       $request = Request::create('your-route', 'GET', $args);
       return Route::dispatch($request)->getContent();
    }
));
```

But you have to create a similar route as well, so it'll be launched to the target but this is an opinion only because still now not sure what you are exactly trying to do, just from a guess.

Comment: been trying similar things: you need to take the uses & as off or the function doesn't even call. After that, can't get the syntax on Request::create correct - not in API docs